# Compiling with gcc (cygwin on windows)

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I have cygwin on windows through which I run gcc. But after creating .exe files, if I run them on other computers which dont have cygwin, it says cygwin1.dll not found. Is there a way to compile them so that they run on any system?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your case, try to copy *cygwin1.dll* as well (but it could depend on other DLLs as well) (of course you must comply with Cygwin's [license](http://cygwin.com/license.html) with regards to distributing  cygwin1.dll)
In cygwin, you can always check the needed modules using:

```
objdump -p a.exe | grep 'DLL Name'
```

OR

```
cygcheck ./a.exe
```

or for windows in general, use something like this tool: [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: cygcheck says: "Error: could not find a.exe" if I write "cygcheck a.exe"

Answer (score 12):

You need to compile for MinGW (Minimal GNU Win32) mode. You do that by either installing [mingw](http://mingw.org/) instead of (or in addition to) cygwin, or by passing the --mno-cygwin compiler option to the cygwin gcc.

Comment: But i m using fork function in my program. If I use -mno-cygwin, it says fork not defined.

Comment: Then you will have to provide cygwin1.dll to your users. Windows itself does not provide a fork() system call. It would be best to rewrite your code to not use fork anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You can try compiling with the command line option `-mno-cygwin`.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Cygwin FAQ](http://www.cygwin.com/faq/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.bundling-cygwin).

Answer (score 0):

From http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.programming.win32-no-cygwin

How do I compile a Win32 executable that doesn't use Cygwin?

The compilers provided by the mingw-gcc, mingw64-i686-gcc, and mingw64-x86_64-gcc packages link against standard Microsoft DLLs instead of Cygwin. This is desirable for native Windows programs that don't need a UNIX emulation layer.

This is not to be confused with 'MinGW' (Minimalist GNU for Windows), which is a completely separate effort.