# fork with gcc on windows

Tags: gcc, cygwin, fork

I am using fork in my program on windows using gcc (cygwin). It runs fine on my system. but I want to run on other systems which dont have cygwin. How can I do that?

Comment: By distributing `cygwin1.dll` and any other dll's needed in compliance with the licensing terms as pointed out in answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475684/compiling-with-gcc-cygwin-on-windows

Comment: @Sinan: Please make that an answer so I can vote it up!

Comment: why is this question posted twice??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program requires the existence of `cygwin1.dll` on the target computer. One way to ensure this is to tell your users that at least a minimal installation of Cygwin is required. Another way is to distribute `cygwin1.dll` and any other related dll's in accordance with the terms of their licenses. The [Cygwin FAQ](http://www.cygwin.com/faq/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.multiple-copies) has some useful information on this.