# How to disable extension .exe generated by g++ in Cygwin?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, cygwin

In my windows 8.1 machine, I tried to compile the kprogram

```
g++ -o helloworld helloworld.cpp
```

Then an executable file named "helloworle.exe" is created. This is inconsistent with my Cygwin on the windows 7 machine, where the compiled executable is named "helloworld". How do I eliminate the extension generated by the Cygwin g++?

I am trying to keep them consistent so in the git there won't be two files of the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: What's the command line you're using?

Comment: I know this sounds dumb, but you're displaying filename extensions on the Win7 box right?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be committing binary files to git. The state of the repository at each commit should be enough to compile your program.

Comment: Try `g++ -o helloworld. helloworld.cpp`

Comment: @EdPlunkett The fact that Windows hides the extension by default is dumb. ;)

Comment: @leemes -- Don't I know it!

Comment: First thing I switch on on Windows after install, along with 'Show system files' and the like.

Comment: I guess Windows might also complain when asked to execute a binary which doesn't end in `.exe`.

Comment: Why do you keep executables in git to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66603802/3641635) to my answer for the same thing with Cygwin GCC. It works for g++ too.

By telling the linker how to name its output.

```
$ echo -e "#include <iostream>\nclass myClass { public: myClass() { 
  std::cout << \"Hello here is my class.\\\n\"; } };\nint main(int nbargs, char *args[]) {
  myClass *myInstance = new myClass();
  }" | g++ -pipe  -x c++ - -Wl,-oess2
```

This will produce an `ess` PE32 / PE32+ executable file, **not** a `ess.exe`.
The `-pipe` option instructs the GCC build chain to not write temporary files but use pipe between stages instead. The `-Wl,-o` option inhibits the default  `--force-exe-suffix`.

Comment: Please quote the relevant parts of your other answer so users don't have to browse to another answer while looking at this Q&A.

Comment: @Null On a more recent answer in a similar situation, i put the link plus the most part of the original answer and was told it's not a good idea ^^ I guess with time i'll be enough trained to correctly guess the good balance :D

Answer (score 1):

CygWin `gcc` suite *always* generates executables with an `.exe` extension because that's how it runs them in the Windows environment.

If you look into the `<cygwin-base>\bin` directory, you'll find it's swarming with executables with the `.exe` extension. The only files in there without it are the scripts like `zcat`.

It's far more likely that the machine where the extensions don't seem to exist simply has extensions turned off within File Explorer. If you go into `cmd` and actually run `dir` on that directory, you'll see them.